# Multivalue error in aggregating values - Webi 4.2 SAP BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to add a price amount to a dimension but getting an error.

My report contains data from 3 different queries and here is the sample report:

```
Medical_contract Doctor  Y1_price Y2_price Total_billed
123              D1        20       30      50
124              D1        23       30      53
333              D1        40       10      50
432              D2        43       10      53
444              D2        56       20      76
```

Medical_contract is a merged dimension.
Doctor is also a merged dimension.
`Y1_price` and `Y2_price` are calculated measure fields which has a formula as below:

```
Y1_price = =Max([Contract_price] In ([Key])) Where ([Y1] = "Y") 
Y2_price = =Max([Contract_price] In ([Key])) Where ([Y2] = "Y")
```

`[Key]` is a dimension variable which contains a combination of different merged dimensions in my query...

Expected result:

```
Doctor  Total
D1      153
D2      129
```

But when I try to aggregate, it gives me error...

> #multivalue error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please create detail variables for [Y1], [Y2],[Key] if not already done and then aggregate.